# I need a powershell script to automate the task of saving data into a text file with out replacing old files in a iterative process

Tags: powershell

I have a .ps1 file that is executed whenever TFS calls it and it's output will be saved to particular file (D:/Deploytest/output/output.txt). If the script is triggered for the second time then the output.txt file is getting replaced with the new content. How can I keep the old file in the folder and add output to a new file?
I was using following command in .ps1 file. How to modify to achieve my task.
`Invokesqlcmd -Inputfile "path" | out-file "D:/Deploytest/output/output.txt"`

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to keep that file, either make the name dynamic (maybe a timestamp) or `-append`. Something like: `out-file "D:/Deploytest/output/output$(get-date -Format MMddhhmm).txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#create path output file horodated
$Outfilename="D:/Deploytest/output/output_{0:yyyyMMddhhmmssffff}.txt" -f (get-date)

#out you command into this file
invoke-sqlcmd -Inputfile "path" | out-file $Outfilename
```